# How to create a loop for rbind

Tags: r, rbind

I have 37 data frames: `ts_1`, `ts_2`, ..., `ts_37`

I want to combine them in a single data frame.

I could do that by writing:

```
ts <- rbind(ts_1, ts_2, ...)
```

How does a loop look like, which does the `rbind` automatically?

Comment: `do.call(rbind, mget(ls(pattern = "^ts_\\d{1,2}$")))`

Comment: that does not work. I have 37 data frames. ts_1, ts_2, ..., ts_37. how can I create a list with all those names?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have them in a list:

```
do.call("rbind", df_list)
```

Comment: And what do you want to loop over (as you explicitly ask for a loop)? There are only two data structures in R that allow you to hold data frames together and loop over them: list and environment. The latter you can convert to a list for the purpose of calling do.call.

Comment: so I should create a list (with a loop) and then use the code you suggested?

Comment: No need for a loop:  `mylist<-ls(pattern='ts_')`

Comment: ok, now I have a list, but the list does not work with the do.call function! --> do.call("rbind", mylist)

Comment: I think I got it right: do.call(rbind, mget(ls(pattern='ts_')))

Comment: @feder80 +1 for doing the digging and learning more about `R` :-)